# Showing datetimes with different time zones in order according to user's timezone

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have 2 stores in different countries ( Let's say USA and Japan )

And a user using my application in Germany GMT +2

Two stores give me order dates according to its timezone

The store in the USA is located in LA GMT -7
The store in JAPAN is located in Tokyo GMT+9

Let's assume two orders sold at the same time

I want to show  users  the orders in order according to German timezone

My question is how should I store order dates in mysql (timestamp (int)  or datetime) and how can I convert those dates to user's timezone

**--Edit--**

to those who want to convert timestamps to datetime with timezones

```
            $timestamp = 1554280893 ;
            $datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

            $date = new DateTime("America/New_York");

            $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$utc=new DateTime($date->format($datetimeFormat),new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));

            $utc->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

            echo  $utc->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I convert all timestamps to UTC format and store in db. Then I order all data based on user's timezone by using Mysql's CONVERT_TZ() function

Comment: Store the dates in either format, but ensure you convert them to UTC time before saving (i.e. by adding or subtracting the correct number of hours, based on the store's timezone. Then when you come to display it again, get the UTC time from the database, and convert the recorded time from UTC to whatever time zone is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better to save datetime in UTC and display it as per the user's timezone. Convert datetime in SQL query with this `CONVERT_TZ(orderDate,'+00:00','+02:00')`

Answer (score 4):

**UTC is a better format to save the date and time in mysql. Always show this according to the user's zone.**

First: Convert the time before saving in the MySQL.

Second: 
 Use CAST by (in your mysql query)

> SELECT CAST(getdate() AS date);

Hope this will be resolved using mysql date and time functions.
For more info please take a look to this:

[mysql date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This query is working fine in my case, it will be fine also in your scenario.